# Breaking out from a multidimensional array in JS - specific 2 questions

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, while-loop, break

Two questions;

1. what purpose does the `j = 0` serve in the bottom?
2. in code block there isnt a predefined array, so, which array is indicated by coding `arr.length` :

a.) a presumed array out of the example, for the sake of example or,

b.) the returned array when the first loop finishes? how does js compute with that array?

```
let i = 0
let j = 0
outer:
while (i < arr.length) {
 while (j < arr[i].length) {
 if (arr[i][j] < 0) break outer
 j++
 }
 i++
 j = 0
}
```

Comment: `j = 0` resets the counter for the next iteration of subarray. `arr` is a presumed array. Consider using built in code snippet tool on stackoverflow.com to play around with samples like this - pretty good way to figure out what your code does in most cases.

Comment: Hi. I think you may be having difficulties understanding this code segment because this looks incomplete. `arr` has to be set somewhere or this will error. Even if `arr` were set to an empty array there would be nothing to loop through.

Comment: that is the question lol  yea i know there isnt an array present but it might be the returned array of the first while loop, also this is a code about finding the first negative number in an array so code makes sense to me idk. @farhodius i was thinking alike, a presumed array, thank youu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The little snippet seems to be looking for the position of the first negative element in a two dimensional array:

```js
const arr=[
     [5,12,8,23],[15,2,18,-3],[2,1,-7,3],
     [5,2,8,3],[5,2,8,3],[5,2,8,3]];
let i = 0
let j = 0
outer:
while (i < arr.length) {
 while (j < arr[i].length) {
 if (arr[i][j] < 0) break outer
 j++
 }
 i++
 j = 0
}

console.log(i,j);
```

In this example of `arr` the values of 1 and 3 are returned for `i` and `j`. The array `arr` itself remains unchanged.

The same thing can be done in a functional way (ES6) by using `reduce()` and `findIndex()` in the following way:

```js
const arr=[
     [5,12,8,23],[15,2,18,-3],[2,1,-7,3],
     [5,2,8,3],[5,2,8,3],[5,2,8,3]],
     negativesAt=arr=>arr.reduce((acc,ar,i)=>{
       let j=ar.findIndex(a=>a<0); 
       if (j>-1) acc.push([i,j]); 
       return acc}, []);
// return first indexes i and j:
console.log( negativesAt(arr)[0] );
// return ALL indexes i and j:
console.log( negativesAt(arr) );
```

This second approach will deliver not only the first but all indexes of negative values - if wanted.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose is to iterate through a 2 dimensional array. It looks like this code finds the index of the first inner array which contains a number < 0, hence if (arr[i][j] < 0). This code does it a strange way, after the end of the code, i will be set to the correct index. A more correct way to do this is to wrap it in a function, and use nested for loops to iterate through each nested array, and return i when the condition is true

```
function indexOfArrayWithNegativeNum(arr) {
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
            if (arr[i][j] < 0) {
                return i;
            }
        }
    }
}
const array = [[1,2,3], [1,-2,3], [4,5,6]];
let i = indexOfArrayWithNegativeNum(array);
```

Comment: it does the samething with this code you written only does it with whiles. yeah its about finding the first negative element in 2 arrays by nesting loops one another and breaking the whole loop if condition is not met. your code doesnt break its a repetitive loop i guess

Comment: @afyonkes, there's no good way to break multiple loops, and breaking out of a loop instead of having a natural exit condition is also often bad practice. Trust me, using a function and return statement is the correct way to do it. If it's a school assignment and they want you to use "break" (which would be stupid), then you can make boolean "found" which is false until you find the negative element, then set it to true, and check in the outer loop if (found) {break}

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `some` or `every` methods of the Array prototype to break out of loops. Here is the sample with `some`:

```js
const array = [[1,2,3], [1,-2,3], [4,5,6]];

let indA = null;
let indB = null;
array.some(function(subArr, indx) {
  indA= indx;
  console.log('Array iteration: ', indx);
  return subArr.some(function(val, subIndx){
    console.log('Sub array iteration: ', subIndx);
    indB = subIndx;
    if(val < 0) {
      return true;
    }
  });
});

console.log(indA, indB);
```

`console.log()` in the code is just to demonstrate that it breaks out of the loop.